# How deep does make check for dependencies?

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, dependencies

I have the `install` target depend on my `all` target, which then depends on `prog`, the name of the program that needs to be installed. The problem is, when I change `prog.cpp`, and run `make install`, it doesn't recompile. However, when I just run `make`, it does. **How deep will make actually check to see if there are targets that need to be updated?** Because it seems to stop very soon...

Comment: Deeper than that, so the problem is something else. If you don't specify a target on the command line then the target is the first in the file (or IIRC if applicable it's the first target appearing in a file that you include from the file), or .DEFAULT_GOAL, not necessarily "all".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Make" checks dependencies no matter how "deep" they are, but it doesn't do ANYTHING automatically. If "make install" doesn't establish a proper dependency chain leading to the actual build then it simply won't happen.

Example:

```
install:
   cp Program /usr/bin/Program
```

will do just that: it will copy the program and do nothing else.

```
install: Program
   cp Program /usr/bin/Program
```

says that "install" depends on "Program", so before actually doing the commands associated with the "install", make will look for stuff to do about "Program".